# IDM Objects library Document

Tags: c#, filenet, filenet-panagon

I am trying to use IDM Objects in my C# project for managing queue. But I am not able to get any good documents or official document which has all the syntax and documents for the library. For example I want details for the `deadline` attribute of   `QueueQuerySpecification`, which is not mentioned in any document.

I was able to get only below links:
http://www.iprogrammatori.it/articoli/programmazione/art_filenetinserirelequeuecodeinfilenetis40t_74.aspx
http://www.iprogrammatori.it/articoli/programmazione/art_filenetcomeeffettuarelautenticazionelogi_45.aspx
http://www.iprogrammatori.it/articoli/programmazione/art_articolofileneteliminarelequeuecodedifil_79.aspx

Comment: Are you using IDM Desktop, Images Services or Filenet P8? And given the platform/peoduct, which version are you using? It isn't clear.

Comment: @abarisone Yes. I am using IDM Desktop, Images Services as mentioned in the articles i linked in my question.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the reference looking to [IDM Desktop and Web Services Developer's Help](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27009996), downloading the [Dev.zip](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/data/cm/filenet/docs/wsopendoc/40x/Dev.zip) file of the Images Services version you're using.

It contains a `IDMSDK.chm` file (and many others as well) with a lot of information about programming with IDM Objects.

[image: IBM FileNet IDM Desktop and Web Services Toolkit]

Specifically about `QueueQuerySpecification` `deadline` property:

> Deadline Property  Example    Related Topics       
> This property gets
>   or sets the minimum date/time value acceptable for resultant entries.
>   The default is idmQueueNoTimeOut, which accepts all entries.     For
>   example, set the Deadline property when you add an item to a queue.
>   Then you can fetch items that have not been processed as quickly as
>   expected or desired. Also, this property is often used to retrieve
>   incomplete fields in rendezvous queues that have been on hold too
>   long, or entries that have been delayed too long.
>   Syntax
>
> objQueueQuerySpecification.Deadline
>
> Applies to
>
> QueueQuerySpecification object
>
> Data Type
>
> Date
>
> Default Value
>
> idmQueueNoTimeOut
>
> Access
>
> Read/Write